# Compute all possible edges between a set of grouped nodes

Tags: r, data.table, igraph

I want to compute all possible edges between a given set of grouped nodes. At the moment the only idea I have been able to develop is as a grouped cross join functionality I would like to implement with data.table for performance and memory allocation reasons. I basically want to calculate all potential combinations within a group and iterate over all groups.

The classic approach using base R and dplyr for small data sets would kind of look like this:

```
library(dplyr)
IDs <- data.frame("Group" = c("A","B","A","A","B","B","A","B","B","B")
              ,"ID" = 1:10)
# note that I do not know the 

CrossJoin <- merge(IDs,IDs, by=NULL) %>%
  filter(Group.x == Group.y)
```

So I span the full carthesian product and than filter afterwards. Problem with this approach is of course if the IDs dataset gets larger we run into memory issues.

I know basic data.table functionality that deliver the same result:

```
library(data.table)

dtIDs <-as.data.table(IDs)
CrossJoinDT <- merge(dtIDs[, .(Group, ID)], dtIDs[, .(Group, ID)], by="Group", allow.cartesian = T)[ID.x != ID.y]
```

but performance is still poor on bigger data sets.

The result should be the same as in `CrossJoin` or `CrossJoinDT` but more performant for bigger data sets. (`n=100000` entries in IDs)

Thanks for your help!

Stephan

Comment: You can `setkey(dtIDs, "Group")` for a small performance improvement. Also: why do you subset them in the `merge` call? `merge(dtIDs, dtIDs)` will suffice, if keyed. Also2: check `?CJ`

Comment: Pipes, `%>%`, and `filter` is not part of base R.

Comment: @Parfait You are totally right, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: What do you want to do after the cross join? Maybe that will help to eliminate more unnecessary rows